# win32api set cursor position error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

I have made a code that reads 4 pixels on the screen and if they are black it clicks on them
I use it to get infinite score in piano tiles

It was working last night but now I run it and it works but it doesn't press the mouse down so I click manually then I get the error message

```
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

I dont get it

This is the whole code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
import threading

y = 600
one = 1032
two = 1140
three = 1235
four = 1340

def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)

# threading.Thread(target=pyautogui.displayMousePosition).start()

while not keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
    if pyautogui.pixel(one, y)[0] == 0:
        threading.Thread(target=click, args=(one, y)).start()
    if pyautogui.pixel(two, y)[0] == 0:
        threading.Thread(target=click, args=(two, y)).start()
    if pyautogui.pixel(three, y)[0] == 0:
        threading.Thread(target=click, args=(three, y)).start()
    if pyautogui.pixel(four, y)[0] == 0:
        threading.Thread(target=click, args=(four, y)).start()
```